# Indirect lineage sorting between human, gorilla and chimpanzee, does it exclude loci reversals (for example on chromosome 12?)

Tags: genetics

[Insights into hominid evolution from the gorilla genome sequence](https://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v483/n7388/full/nature10842.html) looks at shared genes across human (H), gorilla (G) and chimpanzee (C), and that indirect lineage sorting led to 15% of the gorilla genome being closer to humans, and 15% of the genome being closer to chimpanzees.

In that study or similar studies, is for example the reversed loci in the image below treated as a genetic sequence shared between gorilla and chimpanzee and not with human, or is the specific genes being looked at, so that their position in the genome does not matter?

[image]